# Watin : Get Datetime and perform calculation

Tags: c#, watin

I have a textfield that has a date with the format "12/23/2010".Is there away for me to get the number 23 using watin ie get number from textfield;i'm gonna use it like this.

```
1.Get datetime 12/23/2010 and get number '23' 
2.substract 2 from 23 and store it somewhere[ie: 23 - 2 = 21] 
3.Insert the new datetime number [ie:12/21/2010 ]

string myDate = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).Value;
DateTime time =  = new DateTime();
time2 = time - 2;
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).TypeText(time2);
```

Is this possible?or should i be looking to another way.Ask the user to insert the data instead.

Comment: why are you trying to do that?? the user insert a date and you modify it? I think it will be easier that the user insert it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the value of the date as string 
Convert it to datetime and use AddDays we can use negative or positive value
And insert it into textbox

```
string myDate = this.Elements.textfield.Value;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
DateTime dtNew = dt.AddDays(-3);
this.Elements.ChangeDateActive.TypeText(dtNew.ToShortDateString());
```

That's it thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.TryParse`, `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse from text to a `DateTime`.

If a failure to parse indicates a failure in the code somewhere (which is probably the case here, given that it's a test) I suspect `DateTime.ParseExact` is the most appropriate approach, providing the expected format, culture etc.

Answer (score 2):

if what you want is to subtract 2 days from a date I would do it like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(myDate)-TimeSpan.FromDays(2); 
//its steps 1,2 & 3 in one easy to read line :)
```

This is of course if you are sure the string you have IS a valid date. If it might not be, then you should do what the Skeet recommends, which is using first a try parse, checking if the return value is true, and if it is, then do the rest, and if it is not, send an error message.

Answer (score 0):

consider writing

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(myDate);
DateTime dtNew = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day - 2);
browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).TypeText(dtNew.ToShortDateString());
```